# PhpStorm MySQL connection timeout

Tags: mysql, phpstorm

I use PhpStorm 2016.3.2 and I want to connect my MySQL database.

But, when I want to connect, I have a timeout exception.

I checked the connection hots/port :

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES LIKE 'PORT';
+---------------+-------+
| Variable_name | Value |
+---------------+-------+
| port          | 3306  |
+---------------+-------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql> show processlist;
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| Id  | User | Host      | db   | Command | Time | State    | Info             |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
| 287 | root | localhost | NULL | Query   |    0 | starting | show processlist |
+-----+------+-----------+------+---------+------+----------+------------------+
1 row in set (0,00 sec)

mysql>
```

I have download jdbc connector/j [here](https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/) and copy/past the `mysql-connector-java-5.1.40-bin.jar` file in `/Library/Java/Extensions`. I have add this file to my PhpStorm MySQL Driver :

[image]

My Database connection config :

[image]

I do not understand why he can not connect...

Comment: can you try to use 127.0.0.1 instead of localhost? sometimes it helps.. :-/

Comment: @Wizard I already tried...

Comment: 1) Maybe check firewall (sorry, not a Mac user so do not know how relevant it is) 2) I would suggest to actually use the driver that PhpStorm offers to download (maybe it somehow different) 3) Ensure that your MySQL has TCP as allowed transport for connections (and not just socket/etc)